# filesize incorrect after using gzwrite() and gzclose()

Tags: php, zlib

The code itself is quite large so here is the boiled down version:

```
<?php
//set common headers
ob_start();
//generate the javascript source
$ret=ob_get_clean();
$handle=gzopen('cache/file.js.gz','wb');
gzwrite($handle,$ret);
gzclose($handle);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize('cache/file.js.gz'),true);
readfile('cache/file.js.gz');
```

The fun part. If `cache/file.js.gz` doesn't exist `readfile('cache/file.js.gz');` reports the correct size. If it does exists then it reports the old size of the file.

I have tried adding `fflush($handle)` after the `gzwrite` with the same result. I have not tried unlinking the file before writing. Seems like a superfluous step.

The output files are generally pretty small. The largest being 5kB.

Server Info:

- Apache version    2.2.23
- PHP version   5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `clearstatcache()` before getting file stats

Comment: Cool. Never knew that function existed.